# Drop largest element within level in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to remove outliers in my data by dropping the largest element within an index level.

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],range(3)],names=['Letters','Numbers'])
s = pd.Series([0,2,1,2,0,2], index=index)
s

Out: 
Letters  Numbers
A        0          0
         1          2
         2          1
B        0          2
         1          0
         2          2
dtype: int64

s.groupby('Letters').nlargest(-1)
```

expected output

```
Out:
Letters  Numbers
A        0          0
         2          1
B        1          0
         2          2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should be changed with `group_keys=False` parameter  in [`Series.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) and then is used [`Series.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop.html) by  `index` values:

```
s = s.drop(s.groupby('Letters', group_keys=False).nlargest(1).index)
print (s)
Letters  Numbers
A        0          0
         2          1
B        1          0
         2          2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `idxmax` and `drop`:

```
s.drop(s.groupby('Letters').idxmax())
# or 
# s.drop(s.groupby(level=0).idxmax())
```

Output:

```
Letters  Numbers
A        0          0
         2          1
B        1          0
         2          2
dtype: int64
```